# How to rewrite with spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I am a beginner in programming and I am learning Java.
I'm building a CRUD application with spring MVC as an exercise, and I don't have a textbook for spring, I'm learning Spring by looking at textbooks for JavaEE.

The following is a quote from the textbook, but I would like to rewrite it into Spring.
How can I rewrite JavaEE to Spring?
I don't know how to write in Spring, especially around @EJB and @Inject.

The repository and service were written by me.

//Author entity

1 id

2 autherName

3 birthPlace

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class BookshelfService implements Serializable {

    private Integer id;
    private String autherName;
    private String birthplace;

    @EJB
    Bookshelf bs;
    @Inject
    transient Logger log;

    public String create() {
        Author author = new Author (id , autherName,birthplace);
        return null;
    }

    public String edit(Author author) {
        id = author.getId();
        autherName = author.autherName();
        Birthplace = author.getBirthplace();
        return null;
    }

    // getter setter...
  
}
```

```
@Stateless
public class Bookshelf  {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public void create(Author author) {
        em.persist(author);
    }
}
```

```
//written by me

@Repository
 public interface AutherRepository extends JpaRepository <AutherEntity, Long> {
 }
```

```
//written by me

@Service
@Transactional
public class BookService {
   @Autowired
   private AutherRepository autherRepository;
   private BookTitleRepository booktitleRepository;
}
```

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-crud-thymeleaf learn from this article your all concept will be clear.

Comment: I am studying spring MVC instead of boot.And there was no mention of EJBs, etc.
Thanks for your comment.

Comment: if you can reach up to here then I guess can go through various resources available over the internet to start with spring mvc.